# Origin of the words arithmetic and geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Why are [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) and [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) called *arithmetic* and *geometric* respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Without denying the truthfulness of **Michael Hardy's** answer, I was always under the impression that the reason for connecting products to geometry was due to the fact that the height of a straight edge triangle is the **geometric mean** of the projections of its other two sides onto the hypotenuse. This and the fact that geometric shapes such as rectangles provide a very intuitive understanding for why **multiplication** is commutative.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine a line of length $1$, and the next of length $2$, and the next of length $4$, and then $8$, etc.  The pair of lines of lengths $1$ and $2$ has the same **geometric shape** as the pair of lengths $2$ and $4$, and similarly $4$ and $8$, etc.