# Why is a geometric progression called so?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, geometric-progressions

Just curious about why geometric progression is called so. Is it related to geometry?

Comment: See, https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110329104007AAwq7GY  and http://www.quora.com/Why-is-geometric-progression-called-so

Comment: See also the Geometric Mean entry from the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/g.html). Unfortunately, this doesn't explain the "why", but it provides some leads for further investigation.

Comment: @Blue: kudos for a useful reference to the actual history.

Comment: Older questions that missed out on becoming popular: [Arithmetic and geometric sequences: where does their name come from?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/820680) and [Origin of the words arithmetic and geometric progression](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/967456)

Comment: That linked question links back here to provide more details, so I don't think this one should be closed.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Here is a geometric figure illustrating the geometric progression 
$1,r,r^2,r^3,r^4,r^5,\ldots$:

[image]

Comment: Now that's a good picture! We don't have to worry about whether people were thinking about $8$-dimensional cubes, however long ago the terminology came about.

Comment: So I guess we pick $r$ and draw the edge you have labelled as $r$.  Then the hypotenuse of the resulting triangle is $r^2$?  Can you please post a proof of that?   Does this depend on the length of the other two edges of the first right triangle (the leftmost one with one leg labelled $1$).  You haven't labelled them and they aren't uniquely determined by one leg being length one.  Thank you.

Comment: @GregoryGrant The triangles are all similar, that uniquely determines everything. The second triangle from the bottom is drawn first and then the first triangle is drawn similar to the second and so on...

Comment: I see it now, thanks

Comment: @GregoryGrant Its pretty easy to proof, you can prove it using the properties of similar triangles. Just do an internet search and you will definitely find a very neat proof. ;)

Comment: Yes I proved it, the conceptual leap was to realize the second triangle from the bottom is drawn first.  Then it's easy to show that all right triangles in this figure are similar which follows from Euclid's most basic propositions on angles and parallel lines.

Comment: Is there any useful information that can be read off this figure? What would it look like for the interesting case when $r < 1$?

Comment: @RobArthan If $r<1$, you draw the figure approaching the vertex rather than going away from it.

Comment: Beautiful pictorial illustration of the geometric progression when $r\gt1$. However this is not an answer to the question about the provenance of the term "geometric".

Comment: @Ataulfo I've since become aware of this paragraph from the Oxford English Dictionary: "_Arithmetical progression, proportion, ratio,_ etc. ... relate to differences instead of quotients. The term _geometrical_ points to the fact that problems involving multiplication were originally dealt with by geometry and not by arithmetic." That's the best answer I have for the first part of the question.

Comment: @David K: That´s right. Looking for information about this question I find that hypergeometric series (the prefix “hyper” is well known) are called so because they generalize the geometric series; Pfaff was the mathematician (teacher and friend of Gauss and later Möbius teacher) who introduced this term.

Answer (score 111):

Here's an extremely nice picture illustrating the geometric series and making it geometrically clear how it converges when $x<1$.

[image: Dobbs 1918]

$s-1=xs$ follows from $PN/ON=BA/OA$ which follows from the fact that $\triangle OAB$ is similar to $\triangle ONP$.

Comment: Great added bonus for the (unfamiliar to me) proof for the sum :)

Comment: @nbubis Right, I only knew how to make the geometric series intuitive and visual for $x=1/2$, but this allows one to do it for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @AlecTeal It's this one: http://www.amazon.com/Plane-Trigonometry-H-S-Carslaw/dp/B00BGGHADM/ref=tmm_hrd_title_0

Comment: @AlecTeal I realized you probably meant what book is the one that is referencing Carslaw.  I'm not sure, I found it here: http://imgkid.com/geometric-sequences-formulas.shtml
And I can't seem to find any other reference to it.  It's pretty obscure I guess.

Comment: @Gregory Grant: Really beautiful. And incidentally also "makes" analysis, not just geometry.

Comment: wow ...you da man...finally I understand

Comment: @AlecTeal The image is not from a book; it comes from page 245 of this paper: W.J. Dobbs, "The Introduction to Infinite Series", _The Mathematical Gazette_ 9, no. 135 (May 1918), pp. 242--246, DOI: [10.2307/3605310](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3605310).

Comment: @AlecTeal Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 16):

Let $ABC$ is a right triangle with right angle $\angle ABC$, then if we draw the height $BH$, we have
$$
|BH|^2=|AH||CH|
$$
The geometric mean comes from here...

Comment: Isn't the height of the right triangle just $|BC|$?

Comment: Observe that the right angle is $\angle B$

Comment: Ah, so you mean drop a perpendicular from the point $B$ to its opposite side, then $H$ is the point of intersection?

Comment: Yes...Exactly...

Answer (score 9):

The arithmetic and geometric adjectives come from the Pythagoreans before the Christian Era. Apparently, the expression “geometric progression” comes from the “**geometric mean**” (*Euclidean notion*) of segments of length $a$ and $b$: it is the length of the side $c$ of a square whose area is equal to the area of the rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$. The construction
of the geometric mean with ruler and compass is well known for high school students; it involves "multiplication" and not "addition".

[image]

Comment: This picture perfectly explains why the geometric mean is smaller then the arithmetic mean if $a\neq b$. and equal if a=b. Beautiful. By Thales' theorem its the same as the comment of the right triangle

Comment: Thank you for your comment, dear friend.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that geometric sequences arose as generalization of sequence $a,a^2,a^3,...$. Why is this geometric? Well, $a$ is the length (= 1-dimensional "volume") of line segment (= 1-dimensional hypercube) of "side" length $a$, $a^2$ is the area (= 2-dimensional "volume") of a square (= 2-dimensional hypercube) of side length $a$, $a^3$ is the volume (= 3-dimensional "volume") of a cube (= 3-dimensional hypercube) of side length $a$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Because geometric progressions are based on multiplication, and the most important geometric notion, namely, volume, arises from multiplication (length times width times height). The term “multiplicative” is not used because it already has a special meaning in Number Theory.