# New Idea to prove $1+2x+3x^2+\cdots=(1-x)^{-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, big-list

> Given $|x|<1 $ prove that $\\1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+...=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$.

**1st Proof:** Let $s$ be defined as
$$
s=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\cdots
$$

Then we have

$$
\begin{align}
xs&=x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5+\cdots\\
s-xs&=1+(2x-x)+(3x^2-2x^2)+\cdots\\
s-xs&=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\\
s-xs&=\frac{1}{1-x}\\
s(1-x)&=\frac{1}{1-x}\\
s&= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$

**2nd proof:**

$$
\begin{align}
s&=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\cdots\\
&=\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\right)'\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'\\
&=\frac{0-(-1)}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$

**3rd Proof:**

$$
\begin{align}
s=&1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+\cdots\\
=&1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots\\
&+0+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots\\
&+0+0+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots\\
&+0+0+0+x^3+x^4+x^5+\cdots\\
&+\cdots
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
s&=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{x^2}{1-x}+\frac{x^3}{1-x}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+...}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{1-x}}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$

These are my three proofs to date. I'm looking for more ways to prove the statement.

Comment: It's the derivative of a geometric series. You just need to find a visual proof for the geometric series.

Comment: This might be useful: https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/a-visual-proof-for-geometric-series/

Comment: I saw this before , thank you .but my question is about geometric-arithmetic series ! (not geometric only)

Comment: Illustration(s) of geometric series: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281856/why-is-a-geometric-progression-called-so).

Comment: @daryakhosrotash, See  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746975#746975

Answer (score 51):

$${1\over(1-x)^2}={1\over 1-x}\cdot{1\over 1-x}=\sum_{j\geq0} x^j\cdot\sum_{k\geq0}x^k
=\sum_{r\geq0} x^r\left(\sum_{j+k=r}1\right)=\sum_{r\geq0}(r+1)x^r\ .$$

Answer (score 38):

For the special case $x=\dfrac12$:
[image: Proof]

If you accept that $1+x+x^2+\dotsb=\dfrac1{1-x}$, the same picture works — just move the horizontal and vertical lines. Instead of them being at $1,1\frac12,1\frac34,\dotsb,2$, you should put them at $1,1+x,1+x+x^2,\dotsb,\dfrac1{1-x}$. The area of the square is then $\left(\dfrac1{1-x}\right){}^2$.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Not a visual proof, but by the Binomial Theorem, $$(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_0^{\infty}{-2\choose n}(-1)^nx^n$$ Now $${-2\choose n}={-2\cdot-3\cdots(-1-n)\over n!}=(-1)^n(n+1)$$ so $(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_0^{\infty}(n+1)x^n$, as desired.

Comment: (+1) this is what came to my mind when I saw this question. This extends nicely for other powers since $\binom{-k}{n}=(-1)^n\binom{n+k-1}{n}$.

Answer (score 12):

Let $S=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dotsb$.
\begin{align}
\phantom{-x^2}S&=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dotsb\\
\phantom{^2}-xS&=\phantom1-\phantom2x-2x^2-3x^3-\dotsb\\
\phantom{^2}-xS&=\phantom1-\phantom2x-2x^2-3x^3-\dotsb\\
\phantom{-}x^2S&=\phantom{1+2x+2}x^2+2x^3+\dotsb
\end{align}
Adding them together:
\begin{align}
(1-2x&+x^2)S\\
&=1+0x+0x^2+0x^3+\dotsb\\
&=1\\
S&=\frac1{1-2x+x^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 8):

The effect of multiplication by $1/(1-x)$ to the sequence of coefficients is to calculate partial sums: if the original sequence is $c_0,c_1,\ldots$ then the new one is
$$ d_i = c_0 + \cdots + c_i. $$
The starting point is the sequence $1,0,0,\ldots$. Applying this operator twice, we get
$$
1,0,0,0,0,\ldots \\
1,1,1,1,1,\ldots \\
1,2,3,4,5,\ldots
$$
In this matrix, the first row is given, the first column is constant, and otherwise the value of a cell is the sum of the cell above it and the cell to its left.

I'll let you figure out the connection to Pascal's triangle on your own.

Answer (score 8):

Problem: For a given integer $N$, how many integers $n_1$ and $n_2$ larger than or equal to zero are there that satisfy the equation:

$$n_1 + n_2 = N$$

We note that it is the coefficient of $x^N$ in the expansion of

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k\right)^2 = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

We can also solve the problem by noting that it is the number of ways you can color N objects with 2 colors. The count the number of solutions, we note that there is aone to one correspondence between colorings and a string consisting of N 0's and one 1. The 0's to the left of the 1 represent to objects with color 1 the 0's to the right represent the objects with color 2. The total number of such strings is equal to $\binom{N+1}{1} = N+1$. This means that the coefficient of $x^N$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ is equal to $N+1$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X \sim G(1-x)$, a geometric random variable with success probability $1-x$. We have
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}(1-x).
$$
On the other hand, we know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/(1-x)$, and we deduce the formula.

We can argue that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 1/(1-x)$ in many ways. One way is to consider $N$ different trials with success probability $1-x$. The number of successful trials is roughly $(1-x)N$, and so the average distance between successful ones (which is distributed according to $X$) is roughly $N/((1-x)N) = 1/(1-x)$. (This argument can be formalized.)

Answer (score 6):

As I'd  suggested like [Calculating $1+\frac13+\frac{1\cdot3}{3\cdot6}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{3\cdot6\cdot9}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot12}+\dots? $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot/746975#746975),

Using [Generalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) Binomial Expansion, $$(1+y)^n=1+ny+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}y^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}y^3+\cdots$$ given the [converge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence) holds

Comparing with given Series

$ny=2x\  \ \ \ (1)$

$\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2!}y^2=3x^2\  \ \ \ (2)$

$(1)\implies y=\dfrac{2x}n$

From $(2),3x^2=\dfrac{n(n-1)}2\left(\dfrac{2x}n\right)^2\iff n=-2$ as $x\ne0$ for non-trivial cases

$(1)\implies y=\dfrac{2x}n=\dfrac{2x}{-2}=-x$

Comment: A suggestion :please show your work with more details .

Comment: @Khosrotash, Please pinpoint your confusion.

Comment: I understand it . no confusion for me .

Answer (score 6):

Here is another variation.

Assuming the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ is known, we consider functions $f,g:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n\qquad\qquad g(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \int f(x) dx&=\int\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n\right) dx
> =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int(n+1)x^n dx\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n+1}+C=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n+C\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-x}-1+C\\
> \\
> \int g(x) dx&= \int \frac{1}{(1-x)²}dx=\frac{1}{1-x}+D
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe $f$ and $g$ have the same antiderivative $\frac{1}{1-x}$ differing by a constant only. Since $f(0)=g(0)=1$ they are equal.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

ie. $(1 - x)^2(1 + 2x + 3x^2 + ...) = 1$

Comment: can you add some describe ? (for the picture )

Comment: It's about same as columbus8myhw's proof

Answer (score 5):

The following proof is far to complicated, but it is a new one and I think it is somewhat funny too.

For $x\in\left[0;1\right)$ we have:
$$
\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2}=\frac{1}{1-\left(2x-x^2\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(2x-x^2\right)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{r=0}^{k}\binom{k}{r}(-1)^r2^{k-r}x^{k+r}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kx^k
$$
We have $c_{2n}=\sum_{s=0}^{n}{\binom{n+s}{n-s}(-1)^{n-s}2^{2s}}$ and $c_{2n+1}=\sum_{s=0}^{n}{\binom{n+s+1}{n-s}(-1)^{n-s}2^{2s+1}}$. Applying the identity $\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}$ we obtain:
$$
c_{2n+2}=\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+1+s}{n+1-s}(-1)^{n+1-s}2^{2s}}=\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+s}{n-s}(-1)^{n+1-s}2^{2s}}+\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+s}{n-s+1}(-1)^{n+1-s}2^{2s}}=-c_{2n}+2c_{2n+1}
$$
$$
c_{2n+3}=\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+s+2}{n-s+1}(-1)^{n+1-s}2^{2s+1}}=\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+s+1}{n-s}(-1)^{n+1-s}2^{2s+1}}+\sum_{s=0}^{n+1}{\binom{n+s+1}{n-s+1}(-1)^{n+1-s}2^{2s+1}}=-c_{2n+1}+2c_{2n+2}=3c_{2n+1}-2c_{2n}
$$
Therefore:
$$
c_{2n+3}-c_{2n+2}=3c_{2n+1}-2c_{2n}+c_{2n}-2c_{2n+1}=c_{2n+1}-c_{2n}=…=c_1-c_0=1
$$
Thus:
$$
c_{2n+2}=-c_{2n}+2\left(c_{2n}+1\right)=c_{2n}+2
$$
$$
c_{2n+3}=3c_{2n+1}-2\left(c_{2n+1}-1\right)=c_{2n+1}+2
$$
Together with $c_0=1$ and $c_1=2$ we obtain $c_n=n+1$. Thus, for $x\in\left[0;1\right)$:
$$
\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k
$$
By observing, that:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(-x)^k+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(4k+2)x^2k=\frac{4}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}-\frac{2}{1-x^2}
$$
We get the analogous result for $x\in\left(-1;0\right]$

Comment: Wow. Just... wow.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$ f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}, \quad |x| < 1. $$ Then $$f'(x) = \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^{n-2} = 2 \left( \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}2x^{n-2} \right ).$$ Note $\frac{n(n-1)}2 = \dbinom{n}2$ so $$f'(x) = 2 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dbinom{n}2x^{n-2} .$$ Now consider the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = (1+x+x^2+ \cdots )^3$.The coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of ways to solve the equation $a+b+c = k$ where $0 \le a,b,c \le k$. Imagine this as $k$ dots where we need to place $2$ bars.

This gives us $\dbinom{k+2}2$ ways. Thus, we have $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dbinom{n}2x^{n-2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^3} $$ so $$f'(x) = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$$ so $$f(x) = \int \frac{2}{(1-x)^3} dx = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} +C. $$ Letting $x = 0$ gives $C = 0$ as desired.

Answer (score 4):

Use differences of a sum.

> $$
> \begin{array}{r}
> S &=& +1 & +2 x & +3 x^2 & +4 x^3 & +5 x^4 & +6 x^5 & +7 x^6 & \cdots\\
> -2 x S &=& & -2x & -4 x & -6 x^2 & -8 x^3 & -10 x^4 & -12 x^5 & \cdots\\
> x^2 S &=& & & +x^2 & +2 x^2 & +3 x^4 & +4 x^5 & +5 x^6 & \cdots\\
> &&&&&&&&&& +\\
> \hline\\
> \big( 1 - 2 x + x^2 \big) S &=& +1
> \end{array}
> $$

Or

> $$
> \begin{array}{rclc}
> S &=& \displaystyle + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}\\
> - 2 x S &=& \displaystyle - \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2 k x^{k}\\
> x^2 S &=& \displaystyle + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k+1}\\
> &&&+\\
> \hline\\
> \big( 1 - 2 x + x^2 \big) S
> &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}
>   - \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2 k x^{k}
>   + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k+1}\\
> &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) x^k
>   - \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2 k x^{k}
>   + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1) x^k\\
> &=& \displaystyle 1 + \big[ 2 - 2 \big] x
>   + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \big[ (k+1) - 2 k + (k-1) \big] x^k\\
> &=& 1
> \end{array}
> $$

So

> $$
> S = \frac{1}{1-2x+x^2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
> $$

Comment: It is not the same as " columbus8myhw" ...?

Comment: No. There is a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The sequence $y=(1,2,3,4,\ldots)$ is an output of the linear system
$$
y_{k+1}=y_k+u_k,\qquad y_0=1
$$
for the input $u=(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$. Perform the $Z$-transform (multiply by $z^k$ and add up for all $k$)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty y_{k+1}z^k=\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty y_kz^k}_{y(z)}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty u_kz^k}_{u(z)}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\frac{1}{z}(y(z)-y_0)=y(z)+u(z)\quad\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\quad y(z)=\frac{1+z u(z)}{1-z}=\frac{1+z\frac{1}{1-z}}{1-z}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(1+x+^2+x^3+\cdots)$$ Coefficient of $x^k$ in this expansion is just $k+1.$ Because $$1.x^k+x.x^{k-1}+x^2.x^{k-2}+\cdots+x^k.1=(k+1)x^k.$$ Therefore $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^2=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots.$$ 
Now evaluate (you can use the same procedure) $$(1-2x+x^2)(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots)=?$$

Comment: Also see [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjKyNjzj4_HAhXKcI4KHTm_BUw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FArithmetico-geometric_sequence&ei=KofAVcqLFsrhuQS5_pbgBA&usg=AFQjCNGCIr0vP4VNf2Hc8npElbQEFPKrmg)