# $32$ Goldbach Variations - Papers presenting a single gem in number theory or combinatorics from different point of view

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, big-list

A short time ago I found the nice paper *[Thirty-two Goldbach Variations](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502034)* written by J.M. Borwein and D.M. Bradley. It presents $32$ *different proofs* of the Euler sum identity

\begin{align*}
\zeta(2,1)=\zeta(3)=8\zeta(\overline{2},1)
\end{align*}

> Such a walk through different methods around a single theme is for me an extraordinary pleasure and a good opportunity to associate and to link aspects which I wasn't aware before.
>
> Here I'm asking for papers like this one which present a *single gem* and  provide us with an anthology of different representions, or different proofs or other aspects around this gem. To keep the selection managable I'd like to put the focus on *number theory* and *combinatorics*.

Two more examples which perfectly match my requirements/wishes:

- *[Catalan Addendum](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf)* by R.P. Stanley provides us with a wealth of different representations of Catalan Numbers extending his $66$ combinatorial representations from the second volume of his classic *[Enumerative Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/)*.
- *[The Harmonic Series Diverges Again and Again](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/harmapa.pdf)* by *S.J. Kifowit* and *T.A. Stamps*
  presenting some rather elementary proofs together with the follow-up paper *[More Proofs of Divergence of the Harmonic Series](http://stevekifowit.com/pubs/harm2.pdf)*.

Comment: Good papers and good question! (+1)

Comment: Not a paper, but a list: http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/rchrono.html This is probably the single theorem across mathematics most worthy of collecting different proofs for.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Great list, many thanks! ... and good characterisation :-)

Comment: I'm sure someone has made a collection of proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt2$. There are quite a few at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elisha S. Loomis, [*The Pythagorean Proposition*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873530365), contains $370$ proofs of the Pythagorean theorem. [ERIC](http://files.eric.ed.gov) has a [PDF](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED037335.pdf) of NCTM reissue of the $1940$ second edition.

Comment: Wonderful reference! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

[Fourteen Proofs of a Result About Tiling a Rectangle](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Wagon601-617.pdf) collects $14$ proofs of the fact that a rectangle tiled by rectangles each of which has at least an integer side has an integer side.

Answer (score 2):

Robin Chapman gives [many](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf) proofs of $\sum n^{-2}=\pi^2/6$.

Answer (score 2):

The book "The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra" by Fine and Rosenberger ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=MenlBwAAQBAJ)) contains detailed discussions of at least six proofs of this theorem, all rooted in different areas of mathematics.  Links to other papers (not all in English) compiling various proofs of the theorem can be found at [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra).

H. W. Kuhn gave a [combinatorial proof](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0121246) in 1974.

Comment: The link points to good old Springer who kindly is asking only 
$29.95 / €24.95 / £19.95 for a copy.

Comment: @marty-cohen I'd be glad to update it to cite an open-source reference if someone finds one. Or come up with my own proof.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372958/new-idea-to-prove-12x3x2-cdots-1-x-2/) is a question on this site with a whole bunch of proofs of $\sum(n+1)x^n=(1-x)^{-2}$.

Comment: Thanks  Gerry! I know about this question, since I've also added an answer to it. :-) But, please let's stick to references to papers in the answer section.