# Finding the sum of a complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the sum of the series:
$$ \sum_ {n=1} ^{\infty} {nz^n} , $$ $$ |z| < 1$$

Where do I start from? Can I use the root test?

Comment: Can you sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$? If so, notice that that your series is exactly $z \cdot \frac{d}{dz} (\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n)$.

Comment: The Root Test will tell you that the series converges, but it will not give you the value.

Comment: There was a page where they evaluated this first $$ \sum_ {n=1} ^{\infty} {nz^{n-1}} $$ but I could not find it now. They used a theorem to do that.

Comment: This has been asked very, _very_ many times before on this site.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372958/166353); your equation is that one times $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+z+z^2+...+z^n=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}, \quad |z|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ you get
$$
1+2z+3z^2+...+nz^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)z^{n}}{1-z}, \quad |z|<1, \tag2
$$ and by making $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, **using $|z|<1$**, and multiplying by $z$ gives

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n=z+2z^2+3z^3+...+nz^n+...=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}. \tag3
> $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_ {n=1} ^{\infty} {nz^n} =\left(\sum_ {n=1} ^{\infty} {z^n} \right)^2$$

Comment: The index may be off by $1$.

Comment: I think it's off by a factor of $z$, also.

Comment: Yeah,yeah you guys love to criticise, dont you. Actually I didnt really pay any attention to the indices.

Comment: Thats right. Downvote me.. did that make you feel important ?