# Find a closed form for $f(x):(-1,1)\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(n-2) x^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

> For all $x\in(-1,1)$, the following series converges
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(n-2) x^{n}$$
>   and defines a function $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Find a closed form for $f(x)$, $x\in(-1,1)$.

Appreciating any help, and any methods to solve such things in general.

Comment: and any methods to solve such things in general

Comment: $f(x)/x^3$ has the general term $(-1)^n(n-2)x^{n-3}$ which is the derivative of $(-1)^n x^{n-2}$. This series you can sum in closed form (geometrical series) and then differentiate.

Comment: You should include something of what you know about this problem. (What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or using techniques with which you are unfamiliar. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) [Edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3386107/edit) to add any details; comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: trying to learn this for an exam it's an old exam

Comment: $$
f(x) / x^{3} \text { has the general term }(-1)^{n}(n-2) x^{n-3} \text { which is the derivative of }(-1)^{n} x^{n-2}
$$ first what is f(x) second how did you find x^3

Comment: [This might be useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372958/new-idea-to-prove-12x3x2-cdots-1-x-2/1383933?r=SearchResults&s=18|4.1466#1383933)

Comment: don't understand that