# Why does the geometric series formula intuitively work?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I understand the proof for the geometric series formula, but I don't understand how the formula, $S_n = a_1\frac{(r^n -1)}{(r-1)}$

actually relates to the sum of all the terms.

What operations are taking place in the formula to give the sum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a name for the sum of increasing powers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892037/is-there-a-name-for-the-sum-of-increasing-powers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like to think of it for integers working over different bases.

For example, $9999 = 10000 -1$ is obvious and intuitive.  Written another way, this reads:
$$
10^0 + 10^1 + \cdots + 10^3 = \frac{10^4 - 1}{10 -1}
$$
Then just replace the $10$ with $x$.

Comment: Or the common trick you see is to take the sum $x^0 + x^1 + \cdots + x^{n-1}$.  Call this sum $M$.  Then notice $M*x = M + x^{n} - 1$.  Solve for $M$.

Comment: Oh, so you are suggesting that I do $1+2+4+\dots+2048$ in base $3$?

Comment: No, you'd want to view that in base two, which has binary representation $(11111111111)=(100000000000)-1 = 4096-1$ [might have miscounted some of those]

Comment: Lol, ok.  Anyways, good answer.

Comment: But the moral of the story for me is to use the base 10 example to remember the formula.  Then use that.

Answer (score 2):

Try subtracting these two,

$$\begin{align}S&=1+r+r^2+\dots+r^n\\-(\ rS&=\quad\ \ \ r+r^2+\dots+r^n+r^{n+1}\ )\\\hline(1-r)S&=1+0+0\phantom{^2}+\dots+0^\phantom{^n}-r^{n+1}\end{align}$$

So, we have

$$(1-r)S=1-r^{n+1}$$

$$S=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

So that we now have

$$1+r+r^2+\dots+r^n=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have a geometric sequence (or progression), in our case finite with $\;n\;$ terms:

$$a_1,\,a_1r,\,a_1r^2,\,\ldots,\,a_1r^{n-1}$$

Let's call the sum of the above sequence $\;S\;$ , so

$$\begin{align*}&S=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_1r^k=a_1\left(1+r+\ldots+r^{n-1}\right)\implies\\{}\\&rS=a_1\left(r+r^2+\ldots+r^n\right)\implies\\{}\\&(1-r)S=a_1\left(1+r+\ldots+r^{n-1}-r-r^2-\ldots-r^{n-1}-r^n\right)=a_1(1-r^n)\implies\\{}\\&S=a_1\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\end{align*}$$

Observe that in the above there exists *hidden* induction.

Comment: I understand the derivation of the formula. I just don't understand how the formula itself will provide the sum of terms.

Comment: @TomBrooks Isn't the proof clear enough to understand that?

Comment: What I'm trying to understand are the operations that take place in the formula to give me the sum of terms.

Comment: @TomBrooks Ok, then I've really no idea what you want. Perhaps the other answerers can guess.

Comment: @TomBrooks I'm guessing you might like to look up summation notation.

Answer (score 0):

If ever in doubt, you can try induction.  Notice that

$$a_1+a_1r=a_1\frac{1-r^2}{1-r}$$

So the formula is true for $n=1$.

Suppose that $a_1+a_1r+a_1r^2+\dots+a_1r^k=a_1\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{1-r}$ for some $k$.  See then that

$$S=a_1+a_1r+a_1r^2+\dots+a_1r^k+a_1r^{k+1}\\=a_1\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{1-r}+a_1r^{k+1}\\=a_1\frac{1-r^{k+2}}{1-r}$$

This tells us that if the formula is true for $k=1:$

$$a_1+a_1r=a_1\frac{1-r^2}{1-r}$$

Then it is also true for $k+1:$

$$a_1+a_1r+a_1r^2=a_1\frac{1-r^3}{1-r}$$

And that for any $p=k+1$, it is also true for $p+1:$

$$a_1+a_1r+a_1r^2+a_1r^3=a_1\frac{1-r^4}{1-r}$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The case $a_n=2^n$ is the most intuitive to me because:

$$2^n=2^n(2-1)=2^{n+1}-2^n$$

Then noticing the telescoping sum, the formula easily follows.

If we try to do the same kind off thing with $x$ instead of $2$ we get,

$$x^n=x^n\frac{x-1}{x-1}=\frac{x^{n+1}-x^n}{x-1}$$

$$=\frac{x^{n+1}}{x-1}-\frac{x^n}{x-1}$$

And again the result easily follows by telescoping.