# Sum of increasing powers

Tags: summation

In the answer to a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891876/35883)  someone wrote:

> Let $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / n}$ which implies $\omega^n = 1$.
>   $$ 1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \ldots + \omega^{n-1} = \frac{\omega^n-1}{\omega-1} = 0 $$

I tried to understand this for at least two hour now, and thought, that it maybe had something to do with [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) but I can't quite figure it out.

I think what's confusing me most, is that in other places ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) and yet another [math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892037/is-there-a-name-for-the-sum-of-increasing-powers/1892038#1892038)) the formula for geometric series looks like this:

> for $N$ finite
>   $$ \sum_{n=0}^Nar^n=a\frac{1-r^N}{1-r},\:\:\:\: r\ne1$$

So I don't really see, why the intermediate result is

$$\frac{\omega^n-1}{\omega-1}$$

instead of

$$\frac{1-\omega^n}{1-\omega}$$

Comment: $$\frac{\omega^n-1}{\omega-1}=\frac{-(\omega^n-1)}{-(\omega-1)}=\frac{1-\omega^n}{1-\omega}$$

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. That's what I was missing. I'm sorry. I guess I should be very embarrassed now. :D

Thank you so much. You saved my evening.

Comment: Its funny... none of the answers address your issue.  only the comment above by @user326159

Comment: Don't be embarrassed. Everyone makes mistakes ;)

Comment: Thats maybe because the original post didn't metion what the problem was @Eleven-Eleven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that 
$$(\omega-1)(1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{n-1})=$$
$$=(\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\ldots+\omega^n)-(1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{n-1})$$
All the terms cancel out except $\omega^n-1$, so 
$$(\omega-1)(1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{n-1})=\omega^n-1 \Leftrightarrow 1+\omega+\omega^2+\ldots+\omega^{n-1}=\frac{\omega^n-1}{\omega-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly a geometric series of n terms and of second term $\omega$. Replacing $\omega^n = 1 \rightarrow S(n) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to see this is noticing that $\omega$ is a solution of $x^n-1 =0$, which can be factorized like $(x-1)(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1})$, and so as $\omega$ is not $1$ then 
$1+\omega + \ldots + \omega^{n-1}=0$

Comment: Could the one who downvoted this explain it please?

Comment: I didn't actually downvote, but I'm not sure you have addressed OP's question

Comment: As you can see the question was edited after I made the answer, the original question didn't mention the part he was struggling with. I just did what I thougth could be the problem with the information I had

Comment: I see what you mean.  I don't have any other complaints about your post

Comment: That's a flaw in the system... I really appreciate that you took the time to answer to my question and I'm really sorry, that me editing the question caused you to get a down vote. It also caused some confusion for other users like Eleven-Eleven.

Comment: Don´t worry it's nobody fault, but maybe something has to be done, we all want to improve this place helping each other, but in this situation maybe somethings must change, maybe and advertised to the people who answer.