# geometric figure illustrating the geometric progression 1,r,r2,r3,r4,r5,...

Tags: geometric-progressions

[Here is a geometric figure illustrating the geometric progression 1,r,r2,r3,r4,r5,…:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpsx1.png)

from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281856/why-is-a-geometric-progression-called-so)

What is happening here? With a being the unknown side of the 2nd (=1-r-triangle) and b the unknown side of the third triangle, I know 1/b=a/r=r/x. How do I know that x=r squared? I also know that a/r=b/x. Does this help me? Do I need Pythagoras?

Also, what does this illustration proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the triangles with hypotenuses equal $r$ and $r^2$. We let $r'$ the lenght of the second hypotenuse and we want to show that $r'=r^2$. Because the two triangles above are similar, we have:
$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{r}{r'}$
So, we have:
$$r'=r\cdot r=r^2$$
As shown here, we can show that the sequence $r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n$ is a geometric progression with reason $r$, so:
$$r_n=r^n, n\geq0, n \in N$$

Comment: Thanks. I got nowhere because I was comparing the wrong sides.

Comment: @youdontknowme: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: Sure thing. I got confused by the fact that the second triangle needs to be flipped vertically (along the x-axis).

Comment: @youdontknowme: are my explaination clear?

Comment: Yep, very clear. r is not called "reason", though, but "ratio"'. Thanks again and stay strong, Bergamo.